# Swift - parse json array with empty values

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have a json string that is returned by a webservice. I simplified the string to "[,]" to reproduce the error.

My code to parse is

```
var sample:NSString="[,]"
let data = sample.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

do{
    let d= try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
    print(d)
  }
catch {
    print("json error: \(error)")
  }
```

The error given is

```
json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}
```

The expected would be a 2 dimensional array with NSNull values.

Comment: `2 dimensional array with NSNull values` But your string doesn't represent that. The comma doesn't delimit items, so it's not valid JSON. Empty != nil

Comment: Do you try to create a JSON array ? cf: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization

Comment: As @EricAya says, the JSON in your example is actually invalid. It should be `[null,null]` to fit your expected result.

Comment: And by the way, Thomas, `[null,null]` would be a normal array, not a 2D array. :)

Comment: Yes, you are actually right. it should be [null,null]. The data returned is from a google webservice and the swift parser seems not to be able to parse it. On my android java implementation this was no problem. Is there any library out there which can handle this or any trick ?
Btw: Yes it's of course a simple array ;-)

Comment: Why a 2-D dimensional array? Why not two empty objects? Or two empty strings? How should the JSON parsing code what you expect when only a comma is present?

Comment: JSON response should only be an array or a dictionary, not a string. Please print the response your call initially returns in it's completion